# Maven Build Failure of HelloAnalytics code

Tags: java, maven, gson, google-analytics-api

I am trying to execute the HelloAnalytics code provided by Google using a maven project in eclipse. After adding all the dependencies it seems, the `getDefaultInstance` method of `GsonFactory` class is not being recognised. Can you provide me with the maven repositories for the following:

```
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
```

Comment: share the maven dependency used

Comment: @Mansi Gupta can u share your pom.xml ? it is unclear otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to add the following maven dependencies in your pom.xml file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
```